# fouriernc, math-mode and pdflatex not working together

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

I can't use LaTeX because in my project I am using `.png` images which, from my limited understanding, I need something like PDFLaTeX for. I also need `fouriernc` for the New Century Schoolbook font. I also need math-mode elements like `\in`.

So, combining these 3 things I need doesn't work. If I go back to LaTeX and exclude the images it'll work but I need PDFLaTeX for `.png` images ..

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the New Century Schoolbook font


\begin{document}

$\in$

\end{document}
```

The error that the above code generates with pdflatex is "`pdfTeX error: C:\.........\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe (file fourier-ms): Font fourier-ms at 662 not found`"

Comment: "...doesn't work" is not clear! Does pdflatex gives you some error messages? Have you try your MWE (without image) with pdflatex?

Comment: 1) Sorry. Error: "`pdfTeX error: C:\.........\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe (file fourier-ms): Font fourier-ms at 662 not found`".    2) Yes, I've tried it without image. Indeed my MWE supplied above is without an image.

Comment: Looks like a faulty MiKTeX installation, or perhaps you've turned off install-on-the-fly package installing. If you use the MiKTeX package manager to remove then reinstall `fouriernc` does the problem remain?

Comment: The map-file for the type1 font has not been activated correctly. The most probably source of the problem is (in a multiuser installation) the existence of local (user) map-file. Check in a log-file of a working document where pdftex.map cames from. If it is in your user profile run (as normal user) in a command line `updmap`.

Comment: Based on the answer below, this is 'too localized' (faulty installation).

Answer (score 1):

*SELF ANSWER*

Re-installation of `fouriernc` ended up working.

Also Ulrike Fischer gave a useful comment.